# how to fix ionic error while building template

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

hi i am trying to build a first app but got some error while extracting

```
? Starter template: my-first-app
√ Preparing directory .\testarashelia - done!
> git.exe clone https://github.com/ionic-team/photo-gallery-capacitor-ng C:\Users\Arashsoft\Desktop\ionic\testarashelia --progress
Cloning into 'C:\Users\Arashsoft\Desktop\ionic\testarashelia'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 420, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (420/420), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (288/288), done.
Rremote: Total 420 (delta 155), reused 347 (delta 89), pack-reused 0eceiving objects:  82% (345/420), 628.00 KiB
Receiving objects: 100% (420/420), 641.00 KiB | 242.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (155/155), done.
Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

        Ionic Appflow, the mobile DevOps solution by Ionic

           Continuously build, deploy, and ship apps
        Focus on building apps while we automate the rest

        Learn more: https://ion.link/appflow

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


> npm.cmd i
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/core@9.0.0 (sha512-6Pxgsrf0qF9iFFqmIcWmjJGkkCaCm6V5QNnxMy2KloO3SDq6QuMVRbN9RtC8Urmo25LP+eZ6ZgYqFYpdD8Hd9w==) seems to be 
corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Arashsoft\Desktop\ionic\testarashelia\node_modules\.staging\@angular\core-7994b28a\schematics\utils\typescript\nodes.js
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Arashsoft\Desktop\ionic\testarashelia\node_modules\.staging\@angular\core-7994b28a\schematics\utils\typescript\nodes.js'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Arashsoft\Desktop\ionic\testarashelia\node_modules\.staging\@angular\core-7994b28a\schematics\utils\typescript\nodes.js'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Arashsoft\Desktop\ionic\testarashelia\node_modules\.staging\@angular\core-7994b28a\schematics\utils\typescript\nodes.js'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\Arashsoft\\Desktop\\ionic\\testarashelia\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\core-7994b28a\\schematics\\utils\\typescript\\nodes.js'  
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\\Users\\Arashsoft\\Desktop\\ionic\\testarashelia\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\core-7994b28a\\schematics\\utils\\typescript\\nodes.js'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Arashsoft\\Desktop\\ionic\\testarashelia\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\core-7994b28a\\schematics\\utils\\typescript\\nodes.js',   
npm ERR!   parent: 'testarashelia'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check thenpm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running   
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Arashsoft\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-16T10_23_24_373Z-debug.log
Error

at new SubprocessError
(C:\Users\Arashsoft\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:40:23)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
(C:\Users\Arashsoft\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:129:27)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit
(C:\Users\Arashsoft\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
```

it got stuck at this part
tarball tarball data for `@angular/core@9.0.0 (sha512-6Pxgsrf0qF9iFFqmIcWmjJGkkCaCm6V5QNnxMy2KloO3SDq6QuMVRbN9RtC8Urmo25LP+eZ6ZgYqFYpdD8Hd9w==)` seems to be 
corrupted. Trying one more time.

Comment: It says `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink` so search for that error.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ionic CLI are you using? You need Ionic 5 for Angular 9. If you didn't do so I recommend installing ionic CLI globally as such.

`npm i -g @ionic/cli`

Also windows in trying to unlink something and you don't have permission. Have you tried executing this in cmd you opened with "Run as administrator"?